# GNU sort file names with prefix and one or two digit

Tags: sorting, coreutils

I would like to use GNU sort to have the file names from a `find` command sorted by the numbers in the name. The name of the file is "cycle" then the first number to sort by, then ".subset", then the second number to sort by, then "." then the third number to sort by. A simple sort does not work, since the first number can one one or more digits:

```
find /tmp/folder/ -name "cycle*"  | sort
/tmp/folder/cycle10.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle11.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle12.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle1.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle2.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle3.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle4.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle5.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle6.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle7.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle8.subset1.2
/tmp/folder/cycle9.subset1.2
[...]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... | sort --debug -n -t/ -k4.6
```

`--debug` will tell you what `sort` considers for the comparison while doing its job.
Remove it for the actual use.

`sort --help` lists the available options, `man sort` might tell more.

Answer (score 0):

Any character can be the field separator:

`-t, --field-separator=SEP`
use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition

`... | sort --debug -n -ty -k2.4`
`... | sort --debug -n -tl -k3.2`
`... | sort --debug -n -te -k3.1`